# How to select a record if it is equal to any record of a column from a different table?

Tags: sql, list, select, conditional-statements

I have a table with adresses, which were separated by spaces into different columns. Since the name of the streets can be made up from 1-2-3 etc. parts, the street suffices are placed in different columns. 
I have a list of the possible street suffices and I want to check the columns and select the records which are matching to any of the street suffices.

For example if I have a table like:

```
C1     C2     C3     C4 
------------------------
Abbey  road
Made   up     street
Some   Other  Weird  lane
Time   square
```

And also I have the table containing the "list" of possible suffices:

```
C5
--------
avenue
road
street
way
lane
square
drive
boulevard
etc...
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
C5
--------
road
street
lane
square
```

Is there a possible way to do this? I was looking for similar questions, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what happens when multiple suffixes match?  Or when no suffixes match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join two tables using  `IN` as condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2
  ON t2.C5 IN (t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t1.c4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly and really simple! I thought it would be something much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the matches using a `join`:

```
select t.*, l.c5
from table1 t1 join
     list l
     on l.c5 in (t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t1.c4);
```

However, this may return multiple rows from the first table when there are multiple matches.

In your sample data, you might want to only match the *last* column.  If so:

```
select t.*, l.c5
from table1 t1 join
     list l
     on l.c5 = coalesce(t1.c4, t1.c3, t1.c2, t1.c1);
```